# Ace Editor get current selected line number and text

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using Ace Editor, but I couldn't find anything in the docs along the lines of retrieving the current selected line number and its text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
selectionRange = editor.getSelectionRange();

startLine = selectionRange.start.row;
endLine = selectionRange.end.row;

content = editor.session.getTextRange(selectionRange);
```

Answer (score 10):

First, define "selected line". Selection in ace may be set across multiple lines. If you mean "no selection is set, current line is line where cursor blinks:"

```
var currline = editor.getSelectionRange().start.row;
var wholelinetxt = editor.session.getLine(currline);
```

If you need exact selected text, see @parchment answer, I was about wrote the same, but it's not needed now.